# Not able to fetch following updates for 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

When I try to use update manager, it is stopping with following errors. Please suggest or help me with this.

```
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_3.2.0-98.138_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-image-generic_3.2.0.98.114_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can proceed to clean the current packages and populated with new updated lists of packages.

```
   sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
   sudo apt-get clean
   sudo apt-get update
```

If the above commands, didn't work. One of the possible reason is network connectivity. Someone from your network or ISP is not allowing a huge chunk of download on your computer. You can try point your resolver to Google's DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) as a workaround.

```
lazam@lazam-laptop:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Hope it helps.